# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, tomcat7

our project is deployed on the cloud but we need to shutdown and restart tomcat7 everyday otherwise  "org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection"   exception will rise, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: you should provide the log and your configuration at least. Are you not using a connection pool?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have a leak somewhere in your code which gets a connection without returning it to the pool (via `Connection.close()`).

Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) exists mainly to prevent cases like this from ever occurring.

I'd look through the code for methods which get a connection but don't call `Connection.close()` in a `finally` block.

I recently wanted to prevent connection leaks but didn't want all of spring's dependencies so I wrote a very simple JdbcTemplate [here](https://github.com/uklance/tader/blob/master/tader-core/src/main/java/org/tader/jdbc/JdbcTemplateImpl.java). You might consider doing the same to avoid this from happening again (or use spring's version)